# Python: filter on a list returning empty list

Tags: python, list, filter

I've done an OS walk and appended the results to a list.

```
exportFolder = []

for files in os.walk(exportLocation):
   exportFolder.append(files)
```

This is the list that is being stored as exportFolder:

```
[('/home/simon/Desktop/Windows.edb.export', [], ['MSysUnicodeFixupVer2.2', 'SystemIndex_0P.6', 'SystemIndex_0A.7', 'SystemIndex_GthrPth.5', 'SystemIndex_Gthr.4', 'MSysObjects.0', '__NameTable__.3', 'MSysObjectsShadow.1'])]
```

I want to search the list for the file 'SystemIndex_0A'

so I use:

```
filter(lambda x: 'SystemIndex_0A' in x, exportFolder)
```

The results bring back an empty list: `[]`

I can see that the exportFolder list seems to be a list inside a list. How can I get my filter to work?

I want to print the SystemIndex_OA file from the list

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use list comprehensions. Also, the result is right... You need to check each string

Comment: I want to filter the SystemIndex_0A.7 file. I don't want to return an empty list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe rewrite your `walk` loop to look something more like this:

```
tgt=[]
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(exportLocation):
    for file in files:
        if 'SystemIndex_0A' in file:
            tgt.append(os.path.join(root, file))
```

Then you don't need to filter a nested list of tuples.

If you *want* to use a list of tuples produces by `os.walk`, you would do something like this (using your example, so we will only use the first tuple):

```
>>> LoT=[('/home/simon/Desktop/Windows.edb.export', [], ['MSysUnicodeFixupVer2.2', 'SystemIndex_0P.6', 'SystemIndex_0A.7', 'SystemIndex_GthrPth.5', 'SystemIndex_Gthr.4', 'MSysObjects.0', '__NameTable__.3', 'MSysObjectsShadow.1'])]
>>> 
>>> path, dirs, files=LoT[0]
>>> path
'/home/simon/Desktop/Windows.edb.export'
>>> dirs
[]
>>> files
['MSysUnicodeFixupVer2.2', 'SystemIndex_0P.6', 'SystemIndex_0A.7', 'SystemIndex_GthrPth.5', 'SystemIndex_Gthr.4', 'MSysObjects.0', '__NameTable__.3', 'MSysObjectsShadow.1']
```

Now that you have used tuple unpacking to unpack the tuple, you can use your filter statement:

```
>>> filter(lambda x: 'SystemIndex_0A' in x, files)
['SystemIndex_0A.7']
```

So if you had a whole list of tuples, you would use two nested loops.

Comment: Thanks this works better because it'll just add the single file into the list.